# Verification of Fourier transformation of Io-sinh function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, indefinite-integrals, integral-equations

I try to match, but it could not match $I_o-\sinh$ Practical Fourier Transform pair developed by Ben Logan, transform pair  also published in [The Practical Application of the Fourier Integral](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol07-1928/articles/bstj7-4-639.pdf)  Campbell, George A 
.Sir  J.F. Kaiser describe orally in interview at section `What is the spectral window?` 
 the function [Interview of J.F.Kaier](http://www.ieeeghn.org/wiki/index.php/Oral-History:James_Kaiser)  about this function
the Fourier Transform pair 
[image] 
Where [image]

This Fourier transform pair widely used in Signal processing, Spectrum analysis and other Engineering and Science fields. 
please suggest me how Bessel function convert into $\sinh$ function by spherically approximation and integral Fourier transform by Ben Logan. Please describe in between steps from $I_o$ to convert into $\sinh$

Comment: The English in this question is incomprehensible to me.